# How to use Tensorflow Lite C++ library on Raspberry Pi 3b+?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

How to use Tensorflow Lite C++ library on Raspberry Pi 3B+ ?

I'm researching object detection on Raspberry Pi 3B+. I have trained own model and converted to lite model. Then I have generated libtensorflow-lite.a with cross-compiling on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What problem did you encounter? Give details.

Answer (score 2):

You have to link the library and use the c++ API.

For the TensorFlow Lite c++ API, have a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc.

I wrote a post about how to deploy an example app, using Qt/QML for the GUI the source code is on Github,  https://mechatronicsblog.com/raspberry-pi-tensorflow-lite-and-qt-qml-object-detection-example/